# How to share build app directory with nginx directory path with docker compose

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, containers, docker-volume

I have a react app, which creates a build folder as path `/app/admin/build` and I want this directory to share as volume to the other nginx container that is running as mentioned in my docker-compose.yaml below. Am I missing anything? I want to share the app build directory to nginx.
However, `/var/www/admin/build` is getting created when checked login into the container but its empty. Can anyone help with this?

`Error: *1 directory index of "/app/admin/build/" is forbidden, client: 172.18.x.x, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"`

Thanks in advance

```
version: '3'
services:
  admin:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./admin
    volumes:
      - /app/admin/build
  web:
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - '80:3000'
    volumes:
      - /app/admin/build:/var/www/admin/build
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd include the files in your custom image for the Nginx component.  The `COPY --from=...` option is typically used with a multi-stage build, but you can also name a preexisting image:

```sh
FROM nginx
...
COPY --from=project_admin /app/admin/build /var/www/admin/build
```

Check with `docker images` to see the name Compose assigns to the built `admin` image, or put `image:` in the Dockerfile to set it yourself.

Then in the Compose setup, you don't need `volumes:` at all:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  admin:
    build: ./admin
  web:
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - '80:3000'
```

The one particular complication here is that Compose doesn't know that one *image* can depend on another, so you may need to manually `docker-compose build admin` before starting the rest of the application `docker-compose up --build`.

In general, exporting files from an image is tricky.  The syntax you show replaces the admin container's build directory with an anonymous volume, then mounts an unrelated host directory into the web container.  There's a different syntax that involves Docker named volumes, but it doesn't work in other environments (like Kubernetes) or with host directories, and it ignores updates in the application.  `COPY`ing the files into the image will be the most reliable approach; redesigning your application to avoid that (maybe letting the backend serve its own static files) is even better.